# avoid NullPointerException check

Tags: java, eclipse, sonarqube, sonarlint

I am using SonarLint plugin (2.1.0) with Eclipse Mars (4.5.0) and I am getting : `NullPointerException might be thrown as listToCheck is nullable here` in this code:

```
if (checkListNotNull(listToCheck)) {
    listToCheck.get(0); // I get here that warning
}
```

`checkListNotNull` is a method that returns true if the list that is passed is not null

Is possible to avoid this sonar warning?

Thanks

Comment: what version of Java are you using? listToCheck == null is better for a nullCheck compared to an extra method. or, from Java 8, you can use Optional

Comment: `checkListNotNull(listToCheck)` is longer and harder to read than `listToCheck != null`, so why not use the latter?

Comment: I changed a little my method but real code checks not null and not empty. return list != null && !list.isEmpty(); I am using Java 5 (needed for the project)

Comment: @OscarBcn warnings you know won't cause a problem, you can ignore. anyway, the compiler just doesn't check what your method does.

Comment: those are sonar warnings (issues)

Comment: Does Eclipse possibly consider annotations?
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/SuppressWarnings.html

Answer (score 0):

Just do that

```
if(listToCheck != null && !listToCheck.isEmpty()) {
    listToCheck.get(0);
}
```

And I think the warning will disapear
(the use of another method seems to be useless in this case; the warning is just here because of Eclipse cannot understand what does your `checkListNotNull` do)

Comment: But you get an exception is you have an empty list

Comment: yes I know that, thanks. I would like to know if there is something to do with my code